# Zend Framework: Alter .ini-Files

Tags: zend-framework, ini

in Zend-Framework, is it possible to save an altered .ini-File?

Because altering the $config-Array is easy, if `allowModifications = TRUE` in `Zend_Config_Ini` is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Zend_Config_Writer to modify your config file

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini('config.ini');

// Modify a value
$config->production->value = 'my_value';

$writer = new Zend_Config_Writer_Ini(array('config' => $config, 
                                           'filename' => 'config.ini'));

$writer->write();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may  use Zend_Config_Writer_Ini, it works fine, but has one inconvenience. It doesn't matter that you used inheritance in your *.ini file, if you change something in production dimension, the whole dimension will be copied to its descendants, except entries that overrides production. You will also lost all your comments, so be careful using that.